# Read and parsing file content in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, isinstance

I have a file which contain entries in the following format:

```
FID=COST|Tolerance=1

FID=(BUY,SELL)|Tolerance=0

FID=[(X,Y),(A,B)]|Tolerance=0
```

What would be the best way to find out if `FID` is a string, tuple or list while reading the file?

A normal `isinstance` test of the value of FID immediately after reading wont work. Appreciate any help.

Comment: If you're reading the file with basic file operations (rather than some kind of parsing library), you'll always be getting strings. Are you asking about how to parse the strings to get actual lists or tuples?

Comment: I am fine with a standard library like configparser too - anything that solves this in the most efficient way,without needing to code raw character parsing routines.

Answer (score 0):

Set A,B,X,Y then use eval

```
try:
   FID=eval("[(X,Y),(A,B)]")
 except SyntaxError:
   print "unknown variable or syntax error"
 if (isinstance(FID, tuple)):
   print "It's a tuple!!"
```

same kind of approach can be used for other types